# How to print path and key values of JSON file

Tags: json, jq

I would like to print each path and value of a [json](/questions/tagged/json) file with included key values line by line. Given the following [json](/questions/tagged/json) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), is it also possible to add the values for each line? If not using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is there another way? I am thinking of something vaguely similar to [snmpwalk](/questions/tagged/snmpwalk) for [json](/questions/tagged/json). Also, is there a technical term for what I am trying to do?

```
$ cat short.json | jq '.'
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Groups": [],
      "Instances": [
        {
          "ImageId": "ami-a",
          "InstanceId": "i-a",
          "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
          "KeyName": "ubuntu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
$ cat short.json | jq -r '[paths | map(.|tostring) | join(".")]'
[
  "Reservations",
  "Reservations.0",
  "Reservations.0.Groups",
  "Reservations.0.Instances",
  "Reservations.0.Instances.0",
  "Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId",
  "Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceId",
  "Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceType",
  "Reservations.0.Instances.0.KeyName"
]
```

Example of a single line from the multiline output:
`"Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId": "ami-a",`

Bonus if the output could be formatted to be used in [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) using copy and paste with value easily detached using linux cut:

```
'.Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId': "ami-a"
```

```
$ cat short.json | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId'
ami-a
```

Comment: the same query it possible to resolve with other utilities, not only with `jq`. For example this is a complete solution `jtc` based: **`<short.json jtc -w'<$_:.>a:' -T'{"{$path}":{{}}}' -ll`**. PS. I'm the developer of the `jtc` unix utility. PPS. I'm not trying to promote my tool, merely showing an alternative approach to the query of the OP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not super knowledgeable on `jq` but I found this on the interwebs and I think it will work in your case:

Cut and paste version:

```
jq -r 'paths(scalars | true) as $p  | [ ( [ $p[] | tostring ] | join(".") ), ( getpath($p) | tojson )] | join(": ")' short.json
```

Easy(er) to read version:

```
jq -r '
paths(scalars | true) as $p
  | [ ( [ $p[] | tostring ] | join(".") )
    , ( getpath($p) | tojson )
    ]
  | join(": ")
' short.json
```

Result:

```
Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId: "ami-a"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceId: "i-a"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceType: "t2.micro"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.KeyName: "ubuntu"
```

And because I want the bonus points, here's a hacky `sed` you can tack on to get the output you want:

```
... | sed "s/^/\'./; s/:/\':/; s/\.0/[]/g"
```

Which outputs:

```
'.Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId': "ami-a"
'.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId': "i-a"
'.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceType': "t2.micro"
'.Reservations[].Instances[].KeyName': "ubuntu"
```

Comment: Thank You! Works perfectly. I also want to add a link I found with a similar solution.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515573/convert-json-file-to-a-key-path-with-the-resulting-value-at-the-end-of-each-k

Answer (score 1):

Using the following `jq` expression, we ensure that both the key and the value part of the output are valid JSON (encoded and quoted if strings, and unquoted if boolean, numeric or `null`).  I have created a helper function, `kv_to_str`, to do the formatting of the key-value string, just for readability:

```
def kv_to_str($k; $v): "\($k): \($v)";

paths(scalars | true) as $p |
    kv_to_str(
        $p | join(".") | tojson;
        getpath($p) | tojson
    )
```

Testing on your data:

```bash
$ jq -r 'def kv_to_str($k;$v): "\($k): \($v)"; paths(scalars|true) as $p | kv_to_str($p|join(".")|tojson; getpath($p)|tojson)' file
"Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId": "ami-a"
"Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceId": "i-a"
"Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceType": "t2.micro"
"Reservations.0.Instances.0.KeyName": "ubuntu"
```

To get something that you can use as a `jq` expression to query for each value, we can make a couple of smaller adjustments so that instead of creating keys like `"Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId"` we get `.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["ImageId"]`.  Note that we leave the zeros in there, which allows us to generate more specific keys for array elements.

```
def kv_to_str($k; $v): "\($k): \($v)";

paths(scalars | true) as $p |
    kv_to_str(
        "." + ($p | map([.] | tojson) | join(""));
        getpath($p) | tojson
    )
```

The key is generated by taking each part of the path, putting it in `[...]`, and converting it to JSON (strings will be quoted, and integer indexes will remain unquoted).  We then join the parts up and prepend a dot.

Testing:

```bash
$ jq -r 'def kv_to_str($k;$v): "\($k): \($v)"; paths(scalars|true) as $p | kv_to_str("." + ($p|map([.]|tojson)|join("")); getpath($p)|tojson)' file
.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["ImageId"]: "ami-a"
.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"]: "i-a"
.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["InstanceType"]: "t2.micro"
.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["KeyName"]: "ubuntu"
```

```bash
$ jq -r '.["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["InstanceType"]' file
t2.micro
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the reversible application whereby I can pass the same identifier back into jq to modify the target value, it's a nice touch. Thank you.